# Self hosted dropbox like software for sync Firebird DB files on Unix

Tags: file-synchronization, centos

Is there a tool for files that are stored on Linux machines (* .gdb) that synchronize the file (or the changed delta) according to the schedule (every hour) to the "neighboring" machine without stopping DBMS?

Comment: Without stopping DBMS? Are you syncing databases?

Comment: @seaturtle, yes.  * .gdb is a file of Firebird DBMS.

Comment: I didn't know _any_ syncing tool could do this with a live database without causing problems. (And with a ".gdb" file extension, I was expecting something debugger-related.) (: